# Large sets of nearly orthogonal integer vectors

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

This question is motivated by the Question 5 from the [2017 Asia Pacific Mathematical Olympiad](https://www.apmo-official.org/static/problems/apmo2017_prb.pdf). To paraphrase, the question asks what is the largest cardinality of a set $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that for distinct $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in S$ we have $\left \lvert \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle \right \rvert \leq 1$. The answer is $n^2 + n + 1$, realized (for example) by the set

$$\displaystyle S = \{\mathbf{0}\} \cup \{\pm \mathbf{e}_j : 1 \leq j \leq n\} \cup \{\mathbf{e}_i \pm \mathbf{e_j}, i \ne j, 1 \leq i, j \leq n\}.$$

More generally, for each pair of positive integers $n,k$ define $a(n,k)$ to be the cardinality of the largest subset $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that whenever $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in S$ are distinct, we have $\left \lvert \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle \right \rvert \leq k$. In this notation, the above result states that $a(n,1) = n^2 + n + 1$ for all $n$.

Certainly, for fixed $n$ and $k \rightarrow \infty$ we can asymptotically estimate $a(n,k)$. For example, for $k \gg n$ we have $a(n,k) \gg k^{n/2}$, since by Cauchy-Schwarz we have

$$\displaystyle \left \lvert \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \rangle \right \rvert \leq \lVert \mathbf{a} \rVert^{\frac{1}{2}} \lVert \mathbf{b} \rVert^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

so if $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ both lie in the ball of radius $\sqrt{k}$ centred at the origin, then the desired inequality will hold.

My question is, for fixed $k$, how does $a(n,k)$ grow as a function of $n$? Can one obtain an exact formula (I am guessing it will be a polynomial of $n$, perhaps of degree $k+1$)?

Comment: This seems related to [frames](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra))

Comment: Certainly $c_k n^{k+1}$ is a lower bound, witnessed by
$$
\biggl\{ \sum_{j\in S} {\mathbf e}_j \colon S\subset\{1,\dots,n\},\, \#S = k+1 \biggr\}.
$$

Comment: @GregMartin and with other constant  this is also an upper bound: if we fix $k$ places with positive, say, coordinates, the remaining vectors (with these coordinates removed) have non-positive scalar products, thus there are at most $2(n-k)$ of them.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I am not sure I understand your proof, could you describe it in more detail?

Comment: @EricNaslund there are $O(n^k)$ vectors with support of size $\leqslant k$: for any fixed support (we may fix also the sign of coordinates) only $O(1)$ vectors. Every other vector $u$ belongs to at least one of $O(n^k) $ families of the type ``given $k$ coordinates are non-zero and of fixed sign''. Look at one such family. Say, the first $k$ coordinates are all positive, let $(v_i, w_i), i=1,\ldots,N$, be the vectors of this family, where $v_i\in \mathbb{Z}^k,w_i\in \mathbb{Z}^{n-k}$. We have $(w_i, w_j)\le 0$ for $i\ne j$. It yields $N\le 2(n-k)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I would consider posting your comment as an answer, as combined with Greg Martin's comment, up to a constant, it finds the size of the set

Comment: @EricNaslund done. The bounds are closer than I expected: the gap is only $O(n^{k-1})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me prove the bounds
$$2^k{n\choose k+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k}2^{j}{n\choose j}\leqslant a(n,k)\leqslant 2^{k}{n\choose k+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k}2^{j}{k\choose j}{n\choose j}$$
which differ by $O_k(n^{k-1})$ for fixed $k$.

The case $k=0$ with the answer $n+1$ is rather clear, so let further $k>0$.

For the lower bound, take to $S$ all vectors with at most $k$ non-zero coordinates, all being equal to $\pm 1$, and also all vectors with exactly $k+1$ non-zero coordinates, the first non-zero coordinate being equal to 1, other non-zero coordinates being equal to $\pm 1$ (this is a natural upgrade of an example suggested by Greg Martin in the comments to OP).

For an upper bound, I use a well-known

**Lemma.** If the non-zero vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_m\in\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfy $\langle \mathbf{v}_i,\mathbf{v}_j\rangle\leqslant 0$ whenever $i\ne j$, then $m\leqslant 2d$.

(sketch of the proof: induction in $d$, for an induction step project all vectors except $\mathbf{v}_m$ to the hyperplane $\mathbf{v}_m^\perp$, at most one vector projects to 0, and we get an example of $2m-2$ non-zero vectors with the same property in dimension $d-1$).

Now an upper bound. We denote for $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in S$ the support of vector $\mathbf{a}$ by $s(\mathbf{a}):=\{i\colon a_i\ne 0\}$. A pair of a  finite subset $X\subset \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and a function $\varepsilon\colon X\to \{-1,1\}$ is called a sign pattern. We say that a vector $\mathbf{a}$ respects a sign pattern $(X,\varepsilon)$ if $X\subset s(\mathbf{a})$ and moreover $\varepsilon_i a_i>0$ for all $i\in X$. Note that if $|s(\mathbf{a})|:=j\leqslant k$ and a sign pattern $(s(\mathbf{a}),\varepsilon)$ respected by $\mathbf{a}\in S$ is fixed, there may be at most ${k\choose j}$ such vectors in $S$: if, say, the coordinates $a_1,\ldots,a_j$ are positive, then their sum does not exceed $k$ (or, if it exceeds $k$, the vector in $S$ which respects this signed pattern is just unique), then these coordinates are determined by the set
$\{a_1,a_1+a_2,\ldots,a_1+\ldots+a_j\}\subset \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.

It remains to prove that there exist at most $2^k{n\choose k+1}$ vectors $\mathbf{a}\in S$ for which $|s(\mathbf{a})|\geqslant k+1$. Call such vectors from $S$ serious. Note that every serious vector from $S$ respects at least $k+1$ different sign patterns $(X,\varepsilon)$ with $|X|=k$. There are $2^{k}{n\choose k}$ such sign patterns, and they are partitioned onto $2^{k-1}{n\choose k}$ pairs with fixed $X$ and opposite functions $\varepsilon,-\varepsilon$ (well, here I use that $k>0$). If I manage to prove that each pair is totally respected by at most $2(n-k)$ vectors in $S$, then I get that the number of serious vectors in $S$ does not exceed $2^{k-1}{n\choose k}\cdot 2(n-k)/(k+1)=2^k{n\choose k+1}$, as needed.

Well, consider a pair of patterns, say, corresponding to $X=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, $\varepsilon\equiv 1$. Write any vector from $S$ as $\mathbf{a}=(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})$, where $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{Z}^k$,
$\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{Z}^{n-k}$. Let us have $t$ serious vectors $(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{v}_i)$ in $S$, $i=1,\ldots,t$, for which $\mathbf{u}_i$ has positive coordinates, and $r$ serious vectors $(\mathbf{u}_i,\mathbf{v}_i)$ in $S$, $i=t+1,\ldots,t+r$, for which $\mathbf{u}_i$ has negative coordinates. The $t+r$ vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_t$ and $-\mathbf{v}_{t+1},\ldots,-\mathbf{v}_{t+r}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ are non-zero and enjoy the non-positive inner product conditions of Lemma. Thus $t+r\leqslant 2(n-k)$, as we wanted.